# How to find the reason for Insufficient Privileges?

Tags: security

I am going through the "Development with the Force.com Platform" book and have run into an issue when implementing the sample application from the book.

The example is to demonstrate manual sharing:

- Two employees from the example organisation have separate roles: *West* and *Central*
- The employee with the *West* role has owner ship of a *Resource* record and creates a **manual share** with *Read Only* permissions so that anyone with the *Central* role can read the record.
- The employee with the *Central* role then has to create an *Assignment* record which involves using the shared *Resource* record and a *Project* record which he is the owner of.

Unfortunately when I try to do this (logged in as the *Central* user). I get the following message:

> Insufficient Privileges. You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested

What I have checked:

1. That there is a manual sharing rule for that *Resource* which shares with *Central* role.
2. That the when logged in as the *Central* user, I can read the record. Which I can.
3. I have tried setting the *Central* users role to *West* (the same as the *Resource* owners') and the *Assignment* can then be created OK.
4. I have checked that the user is indeed set as having the *Central* role.

I really don't see what else it could be. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Rather than just suggestions, though, is there a way that I can find out exactly which security settings are denying this operation? Some debugging perhaps?

Many thanks

Comment: When exactly are you receiving this error message? Can Central view West's Resource record? Can Central open a new Assignment record screen? Can Central save the new Assignment record?

Comment: I think the title of this question should be changed.  The answers here do not answer the question stated in the title, instead they provide *very* specific things to check.  None of the answers say *how to find the reason* for the privilege error.

Comment: This is crazy. I've wasted hours today trying to just figure out why a user's privileges are insufficient. If only Salesforce could tell me *why* the user has insufficient privileges instead of me trying guess and check for hours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe try checking the *Central* user's access to whatever record type your unable to create. Check at the profile and object level.

Also when you try to create a `share` when the resource (object privacy) is already 'public read only' -- the DML throws an `arbitrary exception` - so also check the record is set to `private`

Comment: Hi. Sorry for the delay in getting back to this, but thanks for your reply. When you say check the access "at the profile and object level", what do you mean? I have checked the profile and confirmed that it has access to the object. Is there another part of object-level security that I'm not thinking about here? The sharing rule is in place. The organization-wide default is *private*. The *Central* user definitely has access to the Resource object - it can read it. I'm sure that this is something stupid but I'm not sure what. Shame there isn't a sys admin function to say why the user's denied

Answer (score 1):

Kind of depends on what Profile the employee you are using has....

According to the diagram on page 51, Assignment, being an intersection object is the child of both Project and Resource in a Master-Detail relationship and thus inherits access from the Master.

Looking at page 78 in the book, Sales Rep and Consultant only have "Read" access to the Master records and do not have create access for the Assignments. They both already have read access to Resource.

In fact everyone has read access for Resource, so your sharing rule is not necessary and might cause errors as mentioned above.

Only the Staffing Coordinator and Vice President profiles have the appropriate access to create an Assignment record, so regardless of sharing, only these two Profiles can create Assignment records.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply. The user trying to create the assignment is a Staffing Coordinator, so he has the rights as you mention. Everyone does have **object** read access, but I did not mention that the organization-wide default access level is *private*, so a user will only be able to read a Resource which they are not the owner of by sharing rules or the role hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with anyway to debug that. And I know you asked not for mere suggestions, but that's about all we can do.

You will just have to go over the settings again -

```
security (for profiles as well as roles)
sharing - yea, check again
views (if they use different ones) - to note, I am not familiar with that "book" that you follow, so don't know.
```

Have a look at the following idea on ideasexchange - I believe that if this will get implemented, most of our problems (well not most - maybe some) will be sorted

[Insufficient Privileges - Tell me why](http://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bre1AAC)

Comment: It would be great if they could implement that functionality!